# FormatterKit in PodSec error: couldn't remove 'ca.lproj' after command failed: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have a strange issue when I try to use FormatterKit in PodSec:`pod lib lint` generate the following error:

```
- NOTE | [ARNUHelpersVer2/FormatterKit] error: make directory /var/folders/vy/cw2t3p5s3xsfmjcp9w7t5brw0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods/FormatterKit.framework/ca.lproj: File exists
- NOTE | [ARNUHelpersVer2/FormatterKit] error: couldn't remove '/var/folders/vy/cw2t3p5s3xsfmjcp9w7t5brw0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Pods/FormatterKit.framework/ca.lproj' after command failed: No such file or directory
```

I see no file `ca.lproj` at all at the build directory.(So Xcode try to remove something that not exist)
I read that issue :[mattt/FormatterKit#88](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit/issues/88)
My PodSec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name         = "ARNUHelpersVer2"
s.version      = "0.0.1"
s.summary      = "A short description of ARNUHelpersVer2."
s.frameworks = 'QuartzCore', 'UIKit', 'Foundation',    'SystemConfiguration'
s.description  = <<-DESC
               A longer description of ARNUHelpersVer2 in Markdown format.

               * Think: Why did you write this? What is the focus? What does it do?
               * CocoaPods will be using this to generate tags, and improve search results.
               * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
               * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!
               DESC

s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/ARNUHelpersVer2"
s.requires_arc = true
s.author             = { "Mike" => "myMail@gmail.com" }
s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
s.ios.deployment_target = "7.0"
s.source       = { :git => "git@bitbucket.org:Private", :submodules => true  }
s.source_files  = 'ARNUHelpersVer2/*.{h,m}'

  s.subspec 'FormatterKit' do |ss|
    ss.dependency 'FormatterKit'
  end
end
```

Did any body had this problem?What will be the correct solution so that people who will use my library wont see this kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there was A BUG in CocaoPds which wasn't merged at the time I used it.[FormatterKit Resources Issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3288#issuecomment-86261487)